# Can't find out what's wrong with the strsep() function in C

Tags: c, strsep

I'm new to C and started making a program. Here's how it looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char input[10000];
    printf("  >>> ");
    gets(input);
    printf("\n\n");
    if (strlen(input) > 10000) {
        printf(" Input too long (INPUT LENGTH = %d)\n", strlen(input));
        return 0;
    } else {
        char processed_input[10000];
        strcpy(processed_input, strsep(input, '$')); //The error is thrown here every time.
        if (processed_input[0] == *"calculate") {
            printf("helo");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It isn't completed yet, but my progress stopped when I tried to test run it and it threw this error:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function 'strsep' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         strcpy(processed_input, strsep(input, '$'));
                                 ^~~~~~

warning: passing argument 2 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'int'
 _CRTIMP __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW  char *strcpy (char *, const char *);
                                        ^~~~~~
```

Can someone please tell me how to fix it?

I tried ChatGPT, other questions of people in Stack Overflow and other platforms, but I still can't find out how to fix it.

Comment: Stop using `gets()` immediately. It's a dangerous function because you can't specify the buffer size to prevent overflow. It has been removed from the language.

Comment: `strsep()` is not a standard C function, it's a LInux addition. It doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: Use `strtok()` or `strtok_r()` instead.

Comment: Anyway, the max string length is only `9999` here.

Comment: @Barmar _it's a LInux addition_ - nops, is BSD 4.3 stuff (older than Linux)

Comment: @DavidRanieri OK, but still not C.

Answer (score 3):

`strsep()` is not a standard C function, it is available on most unix systems, including linux and macOS, but it might not be present on Windows or other legacy systems.

Like other unix functions, it might just have been renamed for historical reasons on Windows, so you can try adding this after the `#include` lines:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define strsep(a, b)  _strsep(a, b)
#endif
```

If this does not work, use my public domain implementation posted below.

For clarity, here is an abstract of the BSD manual page for `strsep`:

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
>
> char *strsep(char **stringp, const char *delim);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `strsep()` function locates, in the string referenced by `*stringp`, the first occurrence of any character in the string `delim` (or the terminating `'\0'` character) and replaces it with a `'\0'`.  The location of the next character after the delimiter character (or `NULL`, if the end of the string was reached) is stored in `*stringp`.  The original value of `*stringp` is returned.
>
> An "empty" field (i.e., a character in the string `delim` occurs as the first character of `*stringp`) can be detected by comparing the location referenced by the returned pointer to `\0'.
>
> If `*stringp` is initially `NULL`, `strsep()` returns `NULL`.
>
> **HISTORY**
> The `strsep()` function is intended as a replacement for the `strtok()` function.  While the `strtok()` function should be preferred for portability reasons (it conforms to ISO/IEC 9899:1990 ("ISO C90")) it is unable to handle empty fields, i.e., detect fields delimited by two adjacent delimiter characters, or to be used for more than a single string at a time.  The `strsep()` function first appeared in 4.4BSD.

Note also that your program has other problems:

- you should not use `gets()`
- `strsep()` takes the address of a `char *` as its first argument and a string of separators as the second.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
char *strsep(char **stringp, const char *delim) {
    char *start = *stringp;
    if (start) {
        /* skip all characters in the token (not delimiters) */
        char *p = start + strcspn(start, delim);
        if (*p) {
            *p++ = '\0';
            *stringp = p;
        } else {
            *stringp = NULL;
        }
    }
    return start;
}
#endif

int main(void) {
    char input[10000];

    printf("  >>> ");
    if (!fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)
        return 1;
    printf("\n\n");

    char *ptr = input;
    char *token;
    while ((token = strsep(&ptr, "$")) != NULL) {
        if (!strcmp(token, "calculate")) {
            printf("hello!\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: I'm afraid you are describing a behavior similar to `strtok` which considers sequences of delimiters to act as a single delimiter. `strsep` does not behave this way: `",,"` is parsed as containing 3 empty fields if `delim` contains a comma.